# ChartJS: Show default tooltip onclick

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart.js line chart displaying properly. When you hover over the y-axis gridlines, the tooltips display as they should.

I'm trying to convert this to function on a touchscreen, so there is no hover. Is there a way to add a simple parameter to make the tooltip show on both hover and onclick?

Note, I know I could add a custom tooltip and add all of that functionality - I'm trying to see if there's just a parameter I can add as I don't need a custom tooltip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `"click"` to your `tooltipEvents` list when specifying the options for the chart

```
    ...
    tooltipEvents: ["mousemove", "touchstart", "touchmove", "click"],
});
```

---

In the fiddle below, I've removed all other events from the list except for `click` to give you an idea of how it will be like on a mobile

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8uobybv3/

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this on version 2? Your example doesn't work for me on version 2.

Answer (score 8):

For Chart.js v2, you can [specify those events at the root level of chart options](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-common-chart-configuration).

```
options: {
    events: ['click']
}
```

Comment: What if you still want to be able to access mouse events for example to change the cursor when a data node is hovered upon?

Answer (score 1):

For **ChartJS version 2.8.0**, you will need to add both the `click` and `mouseout` events to make the tooltip behave the desired way.

The `click` event would make the tooltip to appear when point is clicked and the `mouseout` event would hide the tooltip when the mouse pointer is moved outside of the chart canvas area which is the desired behavior.

**Note: Without adding the `mouseout` event the tooltip would not hide even when the mouse is moved or clicked outside the chart canvas area.**

**Code:**

```
options: {
  events: ["click", "mouseout"],
....
...
```